# custom keys for android keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I would like to customize the keys on the android soft keyboard.  For example, on the qwerty keyboard, I would like to replace some of the letters with unicode keys.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the layout of keyboard by  custom keyboard. you can chage that color of key and background and so other.
You can get the demo of that [Here](https://github.com/zeuxisoo/android-emoji-keyboard) this may be very helpful  for this.